# Outlook Add-In API Office365

Tags: javascript, api, sharepoint, outlook, add-in

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In for **Outlook Online O365** with Javascript code.
Through the API I retrieve the object MailItem (`Office.context.mailbox.item`).

Is it possible to export the  `MailItem` to file .msg and upload it to **SharePoint** Document Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload Mailitem body as Document in Library. To get the mail Item body

```
 var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    if (item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {         
            itemType = item.itemType;
            itemID = item.itemId;
            subject = item.subject;
            body = getBody(item);           
    }
 function getBody(item) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: "callback" }, function callback(result) {
        body = result.value;
    });
}
```

The Body content will be as Byte[]. So that You can create a new document with this byte[]. Also you can get the Attachments. So You can upload that too. Let me know if this helps.